# COUNTIF in access Query

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an Access Query that has computed columns as Rank1, Rank2, Rank3 which can be A, B or C as values.

```
Rank1   Rank2   Rank3   Final_Rank
  A       B       C
  B       A       A
  C       B       C
```

I want to add another column Final_Rank which use the COUNTIF excel formula. For instance, IIF(COUNTIF(Rank1:Rank3,"A")<3,"B",IIF(...))

Is it possible in Access ?

Comment: What would the expected result values be for `Final_Rank`?

Comment: I am not even seeing NB.SI in Excel formulas. Exactly what does this formula do? You want to assign numeric values to the letters and average then convert back to letter value? In Access, build a VBA custom function. How did you compute those columns to begin with? Show sample raw data.

Comment: Sorry, this is COUNTIF function in English. Final_Rank will be another score like A, B or D. First columns are computed thanks to raw data but I want Final_Rank to be computed according to Rank1,2,3 values.

Comment: _Final_Rank will be another score like A, B or D._ Yes, but from what rule(s), and _what would the expected result values be_ for your sample data? What is rank D? Or E and F?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no function in MsAccess SQL that can count certain values across columns, like EXCEL's COUNTIF can. You can simulate it as:

```
IIF(
   IIF(Rank1='A',1,0)+IIF(Rank2='A',1,0)+IIF(Rank3='A',1,0) < 3 , 'B', ...
```